# Determine whether the functional has weak or strong extrema?

Tags: calculus-of-variations

> The functional $$J[y]=\int_{0}^{1}((y')^2+x^2)dx$$ where $y(0)=-1$ and $y(1)=1$ on $y=2x-1$, has
>
> 1. weak minimum
> 2. weak maximum
> 3. strong minimum
> 4. strong maximum

I have searched similar questions on this site, so I found that if $F_{y'y'}>0$ or $<0$ determines weak minimum or weak maxima. So in my question $F_{y'y'}=2>0$, so I have weak minimum, so option 1 is correct. Is my solution correct? If not, how to check the weak or strong extrema? Thank you.

Comment: The Legendre condition you found is a sufficient condition for a strong minimum. Additionally, you may notice that the functional $J[y]$ is defined on a convex set and is strictly convex. So, it's not only a strong minimum but also a unique global minimum.